# AngularJS Form Reset / angular.copy copying empty object instead of expected original data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have looked at various form reset examples for AngularJS, and they all more or less end up at the same thing -- do an angular.copy from the original data.

However...

When I do an angular.copy, it's almost as if it's replacing my form with [] instead of the expected original data.

Portion of the controller:

```
//get my data
$scope.phones = api.phones.query();

//"save" the original state
$scope.original = $scope.phones
console.log($scope.personalphones); //result: [$promise: Object, $resolved: false]

$scope.reset() = function() {
    angular.copy($scope.original, $scope.phones);
    $scope.phones.form.$setPristine();
}
```

Any help or ideas why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a `$resource` when you do `api.phones.query()`?

Comment: Yes sir, blah.factory('api', [etc]){ return $resource('/api/v1/phone/:id', {}, {etc} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `query()` method of a `$resource`, it immediately returns you an empty array. When the server responds with the data, this empty array is populated with the server response. A similar things happens with instance methods of a `$resource`.

So you need to wait for the server response before you copy the array. The array has a `$promise` property on it that you can use to do this.

```
$scope.phones = api.phones.query();
$scope.phones.$promise.then(
    function(response) { angular.copy($scope.original, $scope.phones); }
);
```